# Rotate circular array in place c++

Tags: c++, rotation, circular-buffer

I am having trouble writing a function to rotate a circular array. I need to rotate it in place (no temp arrays) and I need to move around as few elements as possible. For background information the class "Quack" is just a queue mixed with a stack. So items can be pushed and popped off of both ends of the circular array. Here is what I have so far:

```
void Quack::rotate(int r)
{
    front = (front + capacity + r) % capacity;
    back = (back + capacity + r) % capacity;
}
```

front and back are ints that act as indexes for the array. r is the amount to rotate. capacity is the max size of the array.

The problem is if the array has "garbage" values in it, I end up rotating those into the array. For example lets say the ACTUAL array of chars is {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, and front is 5 and back is 3. If I printed the circular array I would see {f, g, a, b, c, d}. Since front is 5 and back is 3, the index 4 is a "garbage" value (it got popped at some point). So my rotate function as it stands has a problem in that the index 4 gets "rotated in". If I rotate the array by 2, the ACTUAL array is still {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, except now when I print it out since front and back are different I get {a, b, c, d, e, f}. What I want to see is {a, b, c, d, f, g}. My print function just prints from front to back (wrapping around as needed) so I need my rotate function to somehow eliminate the garbage value.

I think I need to move the back elements over so I have consecutive values without garbage in the middle. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Have you heard of `std::rotate`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't that swap more than the minimum elements required? I want to swap as few elements as possible and take advantage of the fact that this is a circular array.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but it depends on how your "circular array" is implemented.

Comment: start by finding the minimum absolute distance to rotate (can be forward or back). then move the indices as you're doing, but remember to use `std::copy` to copy the part left behind to the newly uncovered territory. by the way, since the C++ standard library doesn't offer this functionality, it has very little or nothing to do with C++. why the C++ tag?

Comment: I added the c++ tag because that is what I am working in for this project. @40two my circular array is implemented as just a regular old array that keeps track of front and back so I can wrap around as things are pushed and popped.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf that makes sense but i'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. I'm not sure how to calculate what was "left behind". I can see what needs to happen in individual cases, but I can't figure out how to write the code to handle any rotation amount.

Answer (score 1):

So if the array isn't full you need to move some char's around. First you check if r is positive or negative. If it's negative you need to push the back over to be flush with the front for the number r or vise versa. example: 
print out: c, b, a, z, f, g  rotate 2
  a z f g - c b 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6  
the c (items[5]) is in the front and g (items[3]) is back. If we just add r to both it will print garbage for the empty space. If r is 2, we want to copy c to items[4] and b to items[5]. Then items[0] should be the front and b now items[5] should be the back.

```
void Quack::rotate(int r)
{
    if (nItems < capacity) { //if it's not full
        if (r < 0) { // if r is negative
            int r2 = r*(-1); //find absolute value
            for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++) { 
                items[(back + 1 - i) % (capacity)] = items[(back - i < 0) ? capacity + back - i : back - i]; //push back the back chars up to the front r times
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
                items[(back + 1 + i)% capacity] = items[(front + i) % capacity];
            }
        }
    }
    front = ((front + r > 0) ? (front + r)%capacity : front + r + capacity); //if front + r is negative add capacity to it
    back = (back + r) % capacity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a cyclic iterator and std::rotate:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Iterator>
class cyclic_range
{
    public:
    typedef Iterator iterator;

    cyclic_range(iterator first, iterator middle, iterator last)
    :   m_first(first), m_middle(middle), m_last(last)
    {
        if(m_middle == m_last) m_middle = m_first;
    }

    iterator first() const { return m_first; }
    iterator middle() const { return m_middle; }
    iterator last() const { return m_last; }

    private:
    iterator m_first;
    iterator m_middle;
    iterator m_last;

};

template <typename Iterator>
inline cyclic_range<Iterator>
make_cyclic_range(Iterator first, Iterator middle, Iterator last) {
    return cyclic_range<Iterator>(first, middle, last);
}


/// A cyclic random access iterator operating on a iterator range [first, last).
/// If an iterator reaches the last (or is at last) position of the range the iterator
/// becomes equal to the first position of the range.
template <
    typename RandomAccessIterator,
    typename CyclicRange = cyclic_range<RandomAccessIterator> >
class cyclic_iterator
{
    public:
    typedef RandomAccessIterator inner_iterator;
    typedef std::iterator_traits<inner_iterator> inner_iterator_traits;

    typedef typename std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef typename inner_iterator_traits::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename inner_iterator_traits::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename inner_iterator_traits::reference reference;
    typedef typename inner_iterator_traits::pointer pointer;
    typedef CyclicRange range_type;

    public:
    cyclic_iterator(inner_iterator pos, range_type range, bool at_end = false)
    :   m_pos(pos), m_range(range), m_at_end(at_end)
    {
        if(m_pos == range.last()) {
            m_pos = range.first();
        }
    if(m_range.first() == m_range.last()) m_at_end = true;
    }

    const range_type& range() const { return m_range; }

    /// True if the incremented or decremented iterator is at the middle of
    /// the circular range.
    bool at_end() const { return m_at_end; }

    reference operator * () const noexcept {
        return *m_pos;
    }
    pointer operator -> () const noexcept { return &*m_pos; }

    cyclic_iterator& operator ++ () noexcept {
        if(++m_pos == m_range.last()) m_pos = m_range.first();
        m_at_end = (m_pos == m_range.middle());
        return *this;
    }

    cyclic_iterator operator ++ (int) noexcept {
        return ++cyclic_iterator(*this);
    }

    cyclic_iterator& operator += (difference_type n) noexcept {
        if(n) {
            if(n < 0) *this -= -n;
            else {
                n %= (m_range.last() - m_range.first());
                difference_type avail = m_range.last() - m_pos;
                if(n < avail) m_pos += n;
                else {
                    m_pos = m_range.first();
                    n -= avail;
                    m_pos += n;
                }
                m_at_end = (m_pos == m_range.middle());
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    cyclic_iterator operator + (difference_type n) const noexcept {
        return cyclic_iterator(*this) += n;
    }

    cyclic_iterator& operator -- () noexcept {
        if(m_pos == m_range.first()) m_pos = m_range.last();
        --m_pos;
        m_at_end = (m_pos == m_range.middle());
        return *this;
    }

    cyclic_iterator operator -- (int) noexcept {
        return --cyclic_iterator(*this);
    }

    cyclic_iterator& operator -= (difference_type n) noexcept {
        if(n) {
            if(n < 0) *this += -n;
            else {
                n %= (m_range.last() - m_range.first());
                difference_type avail = m_pos - m_range.first();
                if(avail < n) {
                    m_pos = m_range.last();
                    n -= avail;
                }
                m_pos -= n;
                m_at_end = (m_pos == m_range.middle());
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    cyclic_iterator operator - (difference_type n) const noexcept {
        return cyclic_iterator(*this) -= n;
    }

    difference_type operator - (const cyclic_iterator& other) const noexcept {
        return index() - other.index();
    }

    bool operator == (const cyclic_iterator& other) noexcept {
        return (index() == other.index());
    }

    bool operator != (const cyclic_iterator& other) noexcept {
        return ! (*this == other);
    }

    bool operator <  (const cyclic_iterator& other) noexcept {
        return index < other.index();
    }

    bool operator <= (const cyclic_iterator& other) noexcept {
        return ! (other < this);
    }

    bool operator >  (const cyclic_iterator& other) noexcept {
        return (other < this);
    }

    bool operator >= (const cyclic_iterator& other) noexcept {
        return ! (this < other);
    }

    private:
    /// The index of the iterator position.
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    size_type index() const noexcept {
        size_type n = m_range.last() - m_range.first();
        if( ! m_at_end) {
            if(m_range.middle() <= m_pos) {
                n = m_pos - m_range.middle();
            }
            else {
                n = (m_pos - m_range.first()) + (m_range.last() - m_range.middle());
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    private:
    inner_iterator m_pos;
    range_type m_range;
    bool m_at_end;
};

template <typename Iterator>
cyclic_iterator<Iterator> begin(const cyclic_range<Iterator>& range) {
    return cyclic_iterator<Iterator>(range.middle(), range);
}

template <typename Iterator>
cyclic_iterator<Iterator> end(const cyclic_range<Iterator>& range) {
    return cyclic_iterator<Iterator>(range.middle(), range, true);
}

// Test
// ====

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iterator>
void print_cyclic_range(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    std::cout << "Cyclic Range: ";
    for( ; first != last; ++first) {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename Iterator>
void print_range(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    std::cout << "       Range: ";
    for( ; first != last; ++first) {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    typedef cyclic_iterator<char*> cyclic_iterator;

    char v[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
    print_range(v, v + sizeof(v));

    // The cyclic range from 'f' to (including) 'e'
    cyclic_iterator::range_type range(v, v + 5, v + sizeof(v));
    // The cyclic iterator pointing to 'f'
    cyclic_iterator first = begin(range);
    // The cyclic iterator pointing to 'e'
    cyclic_iterator last = end(range) - 1;
    print_cyclic_range(first, last);

    // Rotate the cyclic range from 'f' to (including) 'd', excluding 'e'
    std::rotate(first, first + 2, last);
    print_range(v, v + sizeof(v));
    print_cyclic_range(first, last);
    return 0;
}
```

Giving:

```
       Range: a b c d e f g 
Cyclic Range: f g a b c d 
       Range: c d f g e a b 
Cyclic Range: a b c d f g
```